# finding code of a function in GAP packages

Tags: gap

How can I find the codes related to a function in GAP? When I use "??" in front of the name of function there is no help, so I want to find the code of function among packages.

Comment: Normally the $C$ source code is included with the GAP installation. If it is that what you want. But if you look for the script code then often the command $\mathtt{Display}$ helps. Like in $\mathtt{Display(List);}$

Comment: `??` is used to find the documentation, not the source. For the source, use [`PageSource`](http://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/ref/chap5.html#X845A929B83D46E01). See [this recent thread in the GAP Forum](http://mail.gap-system.org/pipermail/forum/2014/004665.html) for more details. Beware of the difference between _function_ and _operation_: for the latter, `ApplicableMethod` should be used first.

Comment: P.S. Needless to say that if the functions belongs to a GAP package, then this package should be loaded first.

Comment: The answer is actually given in [How does the function CycleIndex work in GAP?](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/114577/)

Comment: This question has no mathematical content and is not within the scope of Math.SE - perhaps that's why it was downvoted. [GAP Support](http://www.gap-system.org/Contacts/People/supportgroup.html) might be a better place for such questions. OTOH, if you would specify which function do you have in mind and say that you're interested to understand the algorithm used, that may fit into the scope of Math.SE quite well.

Comment: Even though this question is quite technical, let's keep an answer here: after all, this may be useful for many GAP users at Math.SE. I am happy to change the function from the example to something else, if there would be any suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

First, GAP is an open-source project, and both the core system and GAP packages are supplied in the GAP distribution with their source code. You may use various tools available at your system to search for a string in the source code, for example

```
grep -R --include=*.g* BoundPositions pkg/*
```

Secondly, you may print a function, for example:

```
gap> Print(BoundPositions);
function ( l )
    return Filtered( [ 1 .. Length( l ) ], function ( i )
            return IsBound( l[i] );
        end );
end
gap>
```

In this case, the code is formatted accordingly to GAP rules, and comments in the code are not displayed.

Thirdly, you may use `PageSource` to show the exact place in the file where the code is contained. In this case, you will see all comments and the author's formatting of the code. For example,

```
gap> PageSource(BoundPositions);
Showing source in /Users/alexk/gap4r7p5/pkg/fga/lib/util.gi (from line 6)
##
#Y  2003 - 2012
##

InstallGlobalFunction( BoundPositions,
    l -> Filtered([1..Length(l)], i -> IsBound(l[i])) );
```

As one could see, this is an (undocumented) function from the FGA package. Clearly, the package should be loaded before using either `Print(BoundPositions)` or `PageSource(BoundPositions)`.

Note that the argument must be a **function**, so for *operations*, *attributes*, *properties*, *filters* etc. one should use `ApplicableMethod` first, otherwise you may see something like this:

```
gap> PageSource(Size);
Cannot locate source of kernel function Size.

gap> PageSource(IsGroup);
Cannot locate source of kernel function <<and-filter>>.
```

Some more details are given in [this GAP Forum thread](http://mail.gap-system.org/pipermail/forum/2014/004665.html) and in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/114577/).